Why does a question of mine not appear in my profile and activity?
I posted a question here back in March 2015:
(bfxor) BruteForcer XOR v1.2 - Data Dictionary Attack on 64-bit Keys
The question was closed by the mods. It is not listed in my profile and activity, however, and visible to myself only after I login and click the link. Why is this the case? Why are other closed questions of mine listed though?
I find this very distracting and I think this is very rude behaviour by the moderators of this board. :(
I've also noticed that some hostile users here are flagging my questions on a regular basis to try to annoy me, to disrupt valid cryptography-related topics and to make me and possibly other "unwanted" users here leave this forum. Now I even get a warning message every time I start a new question:

Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

Sorry for posting a truly offtopic question here (I have no other place on stackexchange to do so) and sorry for swearing, but what the hell is this crap?!
I'm not some kind of lamer or newbie and I don't want to be treated like that. I feel discriminated here!

What happend with the question?
It was closed on March 31 and then deleted by Community (i.e. by the stackexchange software) on April 9.

From criteria for automatic deletion:

If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...

not closed as a duplicate
has a score of 0 or less
is not locked
has no answers with a score > 0
has no accepted answer
has no pending reopen votes
has not been edited in the past 9 days

... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed".

Deleted questions can be viewed by the original poster and users with 10k reputation (2k on beta sites) if they know the link. They're only shown on user profiles to ♦ moderators.
Where does that warning come from?

Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

That warning is generated by the stackexchange software if you ask questions which receive downvotes or get closed/deleted. Once a higher threshold gets crossed, you can't ask questions anymore. See Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account? in the help center. There is plenty of discussion about this on meta.stackexchange.com.

Nicely wrapped up… spares me from fiddling too much with that Print-Screen button. ;)


I find this very distracting and I think this is very rude behaviour by the moderators of this board. :(
I've also noticed that some hostile users here are flagging my questions on a regular basis to try to annoy me, to disrupt valid cryptography-related topics and to make me and possibly other "unwanted" users here leave this forum.

That wasn't moderator behavior, but automatic, like CodesInChaos explained in the other answer. Further, most "moderation" actions like closing are not done by moderators, but by consensus of regular users with enough reputation.
Looking at your question history, your idea of "valid cryptography-related topics" may be different than that of the site. The deleted question, for example, is regarding a tool meant to crack "xor encryption". This is off topic for several reasons:

It's asking about what features cracking programs have, rather than the cryptography behind them.
Asking about where to publish something is similarly off topic.
Both of those are also list questions, which are frowned upon.
It smells like an "advertisement" for your program, rather than a genuine question. Most of the information in the question is just an enumeration of what you've done.
It's not an objectively answerable question, but more of a discussion opener... and this is not a discussion forum.


Every StackExchange site has a very specific scope. Post something outside the specific scope, and the community will vote to close such questions.
Now, if you feel that the scope of the site is too narrowly defined, I encourage you to post topics here on Meta (which is the site for discussing the site) about how you think the scope should be changed. Then the community can decide, by voting. As you can probably tell from my answer, StackExchange sites are very community driven.

My impression is that the OP's problem is less with the scope of crypto.se and more with the stackexchange model of Q&A in general.

@CodesInChaos, That may very well be the case.
